# How do I set up a self signed certificate for development purposes on CentOS 8 localhost?

Tags: openssl, centos

I come to you at my wits end. I've been trying for a day, unsuccessfully, to set up a self signed certificate, so I can continue developing an open source web component.

All the information I could find seems hopelessly outdated, and all I want to do is set up a development server.

I'm using centos 8 and firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ended up using these two: 

`
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/localcerts/localhost.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/localcerts/localhost.key
sudo chmod 600 /etc/ssl/localcerts/localhost*
`

Answer (score 0):

```sh
sudo openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/localcerts/localhost.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/localcerts/localhost.key
sudo chmod 600 /etc/ssl/localcerts/localhost*
```